# OSMemoryBarrier Inside @synchronized Block, Replace With atomic_thread_fence

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, thread-safety

I am upgrading a project and got the following warning from Xcode

> 'OSMemoryBarrier' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use atomic_thread_fence() from  instead

From this method

```
- (nonnull id)objectForKey:(nonnull id)source {
id key = self.keyGenerator ? self.keyGenerator(source) : source;
id value = self.values[key];
if (!value) {
    @synchronized(self) {
        value = self.values[key];
        if (!value) {
            value = self.valueGenerator(source);
            OSMemoryBarrier();
            self.values[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
OSMemoryBarrier();
return value;
}
```

I am still trying to understand how memory barriers and fences work and the part of the code above that is confusing me is the placement of the `OSMemoryBarrier()` calls, and why it needs to be called inside of a `@synchronized` block.

I'm not sure the best way to replace it either, it looks like `atomic_thread_fence()` takes a parameter, and I'm not sure which parameter it should use in either place.